# Question about infinite product with zero term

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that

$$ \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}k=0,$$

or is this divergent?  My thinking is that it should be zero because

$$ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}k=0. $$

Comment: That's a *divergent* infinite product.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Just to be sure, it is divergent even when it starts at k=0?  Obviously for k=1 but for k=0 too?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I think it's convergent, and it's indeed equal to $0$.

Comment: Uh-oh!  Looks like there's some controversy!  Who can provide evidence?!?!

Comment: Infinite products can *diverge* to zero.

Comment: See the discussion in Ahlfors's text on complex analysis. @Arthur

Comment: Saying the product diverges to $0$ is kind of antiquated by now I think. Ahlfors might use this terminology, but Rudin and Conway don't for example.

Comment: @zhw. I suspect that it is less a matter of what is antiquated, and more a matter of the background of the author.  In analytic number theory, a product that multiplies to zero is divergent.  In real analysis, this specific distinction is likely unnecessary.  Note that Ahlfors and Rudin were, more or less, contemporaries. :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your thinking entirely. Infinite products are by definition the limit of the finite partial products. Since each partial product is zero, the limit / infinite product is also zero.

However, as a matter of convention, an infinite product that evaluates to $0$ (i.e. the limit of partial products is $0$) is said to diverge.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Version:** The answer depends very much on how the limit of an infinite product is defined, but I would say that the infinite product is undefined.  We might also reasonably say that the product "diverges to 0" or that it is zero.

In the usual analysis, when we want to find the value of an infinite product, we rewrite it as an infinite series using logarithms.  We then describe the convergence or divergence of the infinite product in terms of the series.  This is distinct from the possibly more reasonable interpretation of the infinite product in terms of partial products.

More specifically, recall that for if $a_n > 0$ for all $n$, then
$$ \log\left( \prod_{j=0}^{N} a_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \log(a_j) $$
for any finite $N$.  Because the logarithm is continuous on its domain, we can pass limits through it.  Hence, ignoring issues of convergence, we have
$$ \log\left( \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{N} a_j \right)
= \lim_{N\to\infty} \log\left( \prod_{j=0}^{N} a_j \right)
= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \log(a_j). $$
It is therefore reasonable to say that an infinite product product converges to a limit $L$, that is
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j = L, $$
if and only if the corresponding series converges to to $\log(L)$.  For example, consider the product
$ \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j}$.
We have
$$ \log\left( \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j}\right)
= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \log\left( \frac{1}{j} \right)
= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} -\log(j)
= -\infty. $$
The series diverges, so the product is said to diverge.  However, it is also reasonable to say that the product is equal to zero, since, if you look at the partial products, they converge to zero.  Such an infinite product is said to *diverge to zero*, which seems like an abuse of language, but is justified by the above argument.

From this point of view, the product that you give can't really be analyzed—the first term is zero, which is not greater than zero, which is a problem.  Looked at another way, the given product can be formally manipulated
$$ \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} j
= 0 \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} j
= 0 \cdot \infty,
$$
as the latter product diverges to infinity.  This is problematic, as well, since $0\cdot \infty$ is one of those pesky indeterminate forms.

Therefore I would claim that the product you present doesn't converge or diverge, but is ill-posed from the start, and therefore undefined.  It suffers from the same problenm as the series
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}, $$
which is similarly undefined (since the first term is infinite).

On the other hand, you can meaningfully give a value to the given product by considering the sequence of partial products.  That is, we could define the product as
$$ \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} j
:= \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{N} j
= \lim_{N\to\infty} 0
= 0. $$
Depending on how the product arose, it might be reasonable to say that its value is zero, or that it diverges to zero.

Comment: I don't think it's undefined. And I know Wikipedia isn't an authority, but it [agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product).

Comment: @Arthur It depends on *how* one defines the infinite product.  I (1) justified my answer with appropriate definitions and (2) offered the answer that the product is zero by analysis of the partial products.  I also disagree with your statement that Wikipedia disagrees with my analysis–note the hedging in the lede: "A limit of 0 is treated specially in order to obtain results analogous to those for infinite sums. Some sources allow convergence to 0 if there are only a finite number of 0 factors and the product of the non-zero factors is non-zero, but for simplicity we will not allow that here."

Comment: @Arthur Typically, all terms are required to be nonzero---complex values are fine.  The difficulty is that if any term *is* zero, then the entire product must be zero.  This is the kind of pointless infinite product that the usual definitions are meant to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the corresponding question for series. Is $\sum a_n$ convergent if $a_1 =\pm \infty$ and $\sum_{n \geq 2} a_n$ converges? Not convergent, right?. The usual **convention** is to define convergence of infinite products in analogy with infinite sums, so the given product is not convergent. (Of course, you may need the value of the limit of its partial products in some proof and you know that the limit exists and is $0$). So this is purely a matter of conventions.